# How to make a regular expression recognise whitespace in html element

Tags: c++, regex

I'm new to regular expressions in C++ and was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here, i'm trying to make a regular expression match a html element, using the code i have i can make it match in all cases except where there is whitespace separating the content from the tags

```
string opening_tag = "(<[[:alpha:]]+>)";   
string content = "([\\w ]*)";   // zero or more characters or spaces
string closing_tag = "(</[[:alpha:]]+>)";
string html_element = opening_tag + content + closing_tag;

regex r(html_element);

string s;
while (cin >> s)
{
    if (regex_match(s, r))
    {
        cout << "matched" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the space with `\s` for whitespace characters: `[\\w\\s]*`

Comment: Hi thanks for reply I tried that but didn't work unfortunately

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1090079) is where *stackoverflow* stands on parsing html using *regular expressions*, it's very relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introduction

Your problem is actually not related to the *regular-expression* itself, but to how you are reading your data.

---

#### Explanation

When using `operator>>` you are effictively reading *"word"* by *"word"*, since the operator will read as many characters as it can find, until it hits a *whitespace* (*whitespaces* are ignored by `operator>>`).

If you'd like to read an entire line from `std::cin` and store it in `string s`, you should use `std::getline`, as in the below sample snippet:

```
while (std::getline (std::cin, s)) {
  ...
}
```

---

<sup>**Note**: The regular expression constructed in your snippet is legal C++, there are however implementations who don't fully support the usage of character classes such as `\w`. As an example, if you are using *libstdc++* you must replace the usage of `\w` with the equivalent `[_[:alnum:]]`, making `string content = "([_[:alnum:] ]*)"`.</sup>

Comment: Hi Filip
Thanks for reply feel silly for not spotting that its working now thanks very much